# How can i change the icon of my site that appears on google

Tags: html, metadata, meta-tags, favicon

[See the image of what i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I4qT3.png)

I tried using <meta property="og:image" content="logo.png">

but it still shows the default which is a web icon

Comment: Hey welcome to SO! This is one of those ones you might want to google first since your question title includes answer(s) on the first page and `og:*` is for [open graph](https://ogp.me/) which isn't the same thing.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

to put the icon on the tab put this code:
`<link rel="icon" href="logo.png">`

Comment: I know of that....am talking of the small icon that shows when the site is searched on google...check out the image link i posted....i have also tried using <link rel="shortcut icon" href="logo.png"> it didn't still show